# Is it bad to have a low entropy in /dev/random?

Tags: linux, random

I wonder whether for the average Linux user it is considered as bad -from a point of view of security or any other relevant viewpoints- to have no or almost no entropy left in /dev/random.

Edit: I don't need to generate random numbers (I would use /dev/urandom for that and even for password generation and disk encryption). Just for the fun of it, I have a bash script that generates strings of random characters out of /dev/random and of course, after playing a bit with it, I am left without entropy in /dev/random and it blocks. On IRC I was told it's "bad" to do so, but I wasn't given any reason. Is it bad because the average Linux user automatically generates random things using /dev/random? If so, which program(s) is/are involved?

I also understand that having no entropy left in /dev/random makes the generation of numbers deterministic. But again, is my computer (the average Linux user) in need of truly random numbers?

Edit 2: I've just monitored the entropy level every second in /dev/random during about 3 minutes, where I launched my bash script that uses entropy to generate a string of random character around the beginning of the monitoring. I've made a plot. We can see that indeed, the entropy level oscillates somehow, so some program(s) on my computer are using /dev/random to generate stuff. Is there a way I can list all programs using the file /dev/random?
[image: Entropy level vs time(s)]

We can also see that it takes less than a minute to yield "acceptable levels" of entropy once the entropy pool has been emptied.

Comment: Why do you ask? What is motivating your question? What scenario do you have in mind? Please **edit your question** to improve it.

Comment: I wanted to keep the original question simple. I have a bash/zsh script that generates strings of random characters using /dev/random and after playing a bit I am left without entropy in the pool : /dev/random blocks. I had been told on IRC that it's "bad" to have no entropy left there, but I don't know the reason(s).

Comment: You should edit your own question, not comment it!

Comment: Why don't you use `/dev/urandom` ? It should be enough for your needs.

Comment: I don't have any need to generate random numbers and I know that /dev/urandom is enough for more than 99% of all needs, including encryption of hard disks, generating random passwords, etc. 
I used /dev/random just for the fun of it. But I've been told that what I do/did is "bad" and I don't know why, hence my question here.

Comment: BTW, if you dont understand something on IRC, you should ask on the same IRC channel, not here !!

Comment: I've already asked on several IRC channels as well as a chess server where they have a linux channel, I didn't get any real answer. If I ask my question here, it's because I really want to know the answer of the question.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: you say, "if you don't understand something on IRC, you should ask on the same IRC channel, not here".  I disagree.  If *X* is an uncorroborated statement about Unix & Linux, then "Is *X* true?" is on-topic for U&L.  There are probably people here who can answer such questions like that more accurately and authoritatively than anybody on the IRC channel — even the person who made the statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Entropy is fed into `/dev/random` at a rather slow rate, so if you use any program that uses `/dev/random`, it's pretty common for the entropy to be low.

Even if you believe in Linux's definition of entropy, low entropy isn't a security problem. `/dev/random` blocks until it's satisfied that it has enough entropy. With low entropy, you'll get applications sitting around waiting for you to wiggle the mouse, but not a loss of randomness.

In fact Linux's definition of entropy is flawed: it's an extremely conservative definition which strives to achieve a theoretical level of randomness that's useless in practice. In fact, entropy does not wear out — once you have enough, you have enough. Unfortunately, Linux only has two interfaces to get random numbers: `/dev/random`, which blocks when it shouldn't, and `/dev/urandom`, which never blocks. Fortunately, in practice, [`/dev/urandom` is almost always correct](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/), because a system quickly gathers enough entropy, after which point [`/dev/urandom` is ok forever (including uses such as generating cryptographic keys)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key/3939#3939).

The only time when `/dev/urandom` is problematic is when a system doesn't have enough entropy yet, for example on the first boot of a fresh installation, after booting a live CD, or after cloning a virtual machine. In such situations, wait until `/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` reaches 200 or so. After that, you can use `/dev/urandom` as much as you like.

Comment: The "rather slow rate" at which entropy is fed into /dev/random is about the order or 1 minute to fall back around entropy 1000 according to my graph. In practice it should be even faster because my monitoring lowers the entropy level and I was monitoring every second.
By the way thanks a lot for the very clear explanation; you've answered to my question.

Answer (score 3):

Having no entropy left *and knowing that* makes `/dev/random` deterministic.
This enable other processes (including those started by malicious users) to be able to "predict" the future output from (i.e. the bytes read from) `/dev/random`.

On one hand, a good Linux programmer in need of "true" randomness would have carefully read [random(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html) so would [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) from `/dev/random`  which would block if no entropy is available. This could annoy processes reading from it. See also (as commented by the OP) the [myths about `urandom`](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/#man-page) page.

On the other hand, some programmers prefer to read from `/dev/urandom` which is almost always good enough and does not block. AFAIK, the C++11 standard library from [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is doing that for [std::random_device](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device).

Obviously, randomness matters slightly more on servers than on ordinary desktops.

If your question is becoming "are Linux programmers using `/dev/random` good enough to be aware of these issues", it is becoming a matter of opinion, or a poll, and then it could be off-topic here.

My opinion is that programmers should be expected to have read [random(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html).

Recent Intel processors have the [RDRAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand) machine instruction, and `/dev/random` is using it (and some other things) as random source. So I guess that lack of entropy on `/dev/random` don't affect (i.e. never happens for) them.

So in short, I don't care about low entropy in `/dev/random`. But I am not coding software (e.g. poker sites, some banking systems) where randomness is critically important (to the point of costing lives, or millions of € or $).
I guess that such systems can afford getting a better random source (IIRC, a hardware random generator with a megabit/second bandwidth costs a few hundred euros), and they should have (or buy consultancy for) expertise on randomness & probabilities.

Perhaps, you should simply mention, in the `README` and the documentation of *your* software, that you are using `/dev/random` and/or `/dev/urandom`, for what purpose, and explicitly document the importance, for your own code, of randomness.

Comment: I have read some not-so-good things about the manual page of /dev/random, see there for example : http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/#man-page. 
I understand that having no entropy left makes the generation of random numbers/things deterministic, but is it bad for the average Linux user? i.e. someone who doesn't generate SSH keys and stuff like that.
Or, is the average Linux user in need of generating truly random numbers? If so, which programs need those numbers?

Comment: Again, your comment should go in your own question.